# unwind segue action doestn't get called

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, slidedown, unwind-segue

I'm trying to build a slide down menu in swift. Everything is working fine except the unwind segue.

I have a CenterViewController where i have implemented the following method:

```
@IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let sourceController = segue.sourceViewController as! MenuTableViewController
    self.title = sourceController.currentItem?.title
}
```

In both VC (CenterVC and MenuVc) I've overridden the prepareForSegue method.

In the stroryboard I "ctrl from the protoype cell to the exit Button" and connected it with the unwind method

However the Action doesn't get called when I touch the cell in the MenuVc 
(I've checked it with a Breakpoint)

I've tried to do it like in [this](http://www.appcoda.com/slide-down-menu-swift/) touturial, but it didn`t work.

Any Ideas where I've made a mistake?

Comment: Does the unwind happen visually without your method being called or no unwind at all?

Comment: it doesn't get called at all.